# Помогите найти ошибку в коде JS

Tags: javascript

Я всего несколько дней изучаю JS.
Есть задачка.
Напишите функцию, которая запрашивает у пользователя число от 18 до 50.
    Если пользователь ввел НЕ число, то сделайте ему замечание,
    если число, то запишите это число в перемнную и используйте в другой функции,
    которая будет умножать это число на само себя, и выведите результат пользователю.

Проблема в том что если сначала ввести букву и при повторной попытке цифру то складывается буква с цифрой и соответственно ответ NaN.
Помогите найти проблему.

```js
function inputSomeValue() {
  var userAnswer = prompt("Введите число от 18 до 50:", "Ваше значение");
  if (isNaN(userAnswer) || userAnswer < 18 || userAnswer > 50) {
    alert("Не правильно :( Попробуйте снова.");
    inputSomeValue();
  } else {
    alert("Правильно! Вы ввели " + userAnswer + " Теперь умножим его на " + userAnswer);
  }

  return userAnswer;
}

var ansver = inputSomeValue();

function sum(x) {

  return x * x;
}
var ansver2 = sum(ansver);
alert('Ответ ' + ansver2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function inputSomeValue() {
  var userAnswer = prompt("Введите число от 18 до 50:", "Ваше значение");
  if (isNaN(userAnswer) || userAnswer < 18 || userAnswer > 50) {
    alert("Не правильно :( Попробуйте снова.");
    return inputSomeValue(); // !!!
  } else {
    alert("Правильно! Вы ввели " + userAnswer + " Теперь умножим его на " + userAnswer);
  }

  return userAnswer;
}
```

Comment: Igor огромное спасибо!!!!!

Comment: @Sergey Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.